# Speeding up a Cython program

Tags: python, performance, parsing, cython

I wrote the following piece of Python as a part of a larger system. Profiling reveals that a large amount of time is spent in `DocumentFeature.from_string`. So far I've tried compiling the unmodified code with Cython and got a 33% improvement in running time. Any suggestions as to how this code can be improved further are greatly appreciated.

Here's the code and the unit tests I've been using.

```
import logging
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import total_ordering
from unittest import TestCase
import nose

class DocumentFeature(object):
    def __init__(self, type, tokens):
        self.type = type
        self.tokens = tokens

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        """
        Takes a string representing a DocumentFeature and creates and object out of it. String format is
        "word/POS" or "word1/PoS1 word2/PoS2",... The type of the feature will be inferred from the length and
        PoS tags of the input string. 

        :type string: str
        """
        try:
            token_count = string.count('_') + 1
            pos_count = string.count('/')
            if token_count != pos_count:
                return DocumentFeature('EMPTY', tuple())

            tokens = string.strip().split('_')
            if len(tokens) > 3:
                raise ValueError('Document feature %s is too long' % string)
            bits = [x.split('/') for x in tokens]
            if not all(map(itemgetter(0), bits)):
                # ignore tokens with no text
                return DocumentFeature('EMPTY', tuple())
            tokens = tuple(Token(word, pos) for (word, pos) in bits)

            if len(tokens) == 1:
                t = '1-GRAM'
            elif ''.join([t.pos for t in tokens]) == 'NVN':
                t = 'SVO'
            elif ''.join([t.pos for t in tokens]) == 'JN':
                t = 'AN'
            elif ''.join([t.pos for t in tokens]) == 'VN':
                t = 'VO'
            elif ''.join([t.pos for t in tokens]) == 'NN':
                t = 'NN'
            elif len(tokens) == 2:
                t = '2-GRAM'
            elif len(tokens) == 3:
                t = '3-GRAM'
            else:
                t = 'EMPTY'
        except:
            logging.error('Cannot create token out of string %s', string)
            raise

        return DocumentFeature(t, tokens)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
                and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)
    # other irrelevant methods removed

@total_ordering
class Token(object):
    def __init__(self, text, pos, index=0):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.index = index

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.text, self.pos) if self.pos else self.text

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (not self < other) and (not other < self)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.text, self.pos) < (other.text, other.pos)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.text, self.pos))

class Test_tokenizer(TestCase):
    def test_document_feature_from_string(self):
        x = DocumentFeature.from_string('big/J_cat/N')
        y = DocumentFeature('AN', (Token('big', 'J'), Token('cat', 'N')))
        self.assertEqual(y, x)

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('1-GRAM', (Token('cat', 'N'), )),
            DocumentFeature.from_string(' cat/N ')
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('VO', (Token('chase', 'V'), Token('cat', 'N'))),
            DocumentFeature.from_string('chase/V_cat/N')
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('NN', (Token('dog', 'N'), Token('cat', 'N'))),
            DocumentFeature.from_string('dog/N_cat/N')
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('3-GRAM', (Token('dog', 'V'), Token('chase', 'V'), Token('cat', 'V'))),
            DocumentFeature.from_string('dog/V_chase/V_cat/V')
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('2-GRAM', (Token('chase', 'V'), Token('cat', 'V'))),
            DocumentFeature.from_string('chase/V_cat/V')
        )

        self.assertEqual(
            DocumentFeature('SVO', (Token('dog', 'N'), Token('chase', 'V'), Token('cat', 'N'))),
            DocumentFeature.from_string('dog/N_chase/V_cat/N')
        )

        for invalid_string in ['a\/s/N', 'l\/h/N_clinton\/south/N', 'l\/h//N_clinton\/south/N',
                               'l//fasdlj/fasd/dfs/sdf', 'l//fasdlj/fasd/dfs\_/sdf', 'dfs\_/sdf',
                               'dfs\_/fadslk_/sdf', '/_dfs\_/sdf', '_/_/', '_///f_/', 'drop_bomb',
                               'drop/V_bomb', '/V_/N', 'cat']:
            self.assertEqual(
                DocumentFeature('EMPTY', tuple()),
                DocumentFeature.from_string(invalid_string)
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.core.runmodule()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By parsing the string using a regular expression, I get a 20% performance increase over your original code.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import re

class DocumentFeature(object):
    def __init__(self, type, tokens):
        self.type = type
        self.tokens = tokens

    _TYPES = dict([
        ('NVN', 'SVO'), ('JN', 'AN'), ('VN', 'VO'), ('NN', 'NN')
    ])
    _TOKEN_RE = re.compile(r'([^/_]+)/([NVJ])(?:_|$)')

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        try:
            match = cls._TOKEN_RE.split(string, 3)
            type = ''.join(match[2::3])
            match = iter(match)
            tokens = []
            for (junk, word, pos) in izip_longest(match, match, match):
                if junk:        # Either too many tokens, or invalid token
                    raise ValueError(junk)
                if not word:
                    break
                tokens.append(Token(word, pos))
            type = cls._TYPES.get(type,
                ('EMPTY', '1-GRAM', '2-GRAM', '3-GRAM')[len(tokens)])
            return DocumentFeature(type, tuple(tokens))
        except:
            raise
```

Comment: This is indeed faster, thank you. One minor point though: the regex is assuming the thing following the forward slash can only have three values [NVJ], whereas my original code doesn't. You couldn't have known that as I didn't make it explicit and the unit tests I provided do not cover any other cases.

Comment: Your observation is correct. `([^/_]+)/([^/_]+)(?:_|$)` would be closer in spirit to the original, but I chose something more strict since the original was excessively permissive.  Feel free to tweak the regex to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I find your error handling is a bit counterintuitive: if the input string is invalid, you return an "empty" `DocumentFeature`, but if there are too many tokens, it raises an exception.  I would raise exceptions in both cases, and let the caller decide what to do.

I think that you're being too pessimistic in validating your inputs: the validation repeats some of the real work that would be done anyway.  Furthermore, counting slashes and underscores is insufficient validation — for example, `"word1_word2//"` passes the initial validation, only to fail at `tuple(Token(word, pos) for (word, pos) in bits)`.  Instead, I would suggest validating as you perform the transformations.

```
_TYPES = dict([
    ('NVN', 'SVO'), ('JN', 'AN'), ('VN', 'VO'), ('NN', 'NN')
])

@classmethod
def from_string(cls, string):
    """
    Takes a string representing a DocumentFeature and creates and object out of it. String format is
    "word/PoS" or "word1/PoS1_word2/PoS2",... The type of the feature will be inferred from the length and
    PoS tags of the input string. 

    :type string: str
    """
    try:
        tokens = string.strip().split('_')
        if len(tokens) > 3:
            raise ValueError('Document feature %s is too long' % string)

        tokens = [token.split('/') for token in tokens]

        # Check for too many slashes, too few slashes, or empty words
        if not all(map(lambda token: len(token) == 2 and token[0], tokens)):
            raise ValueError('Invalid document feature %s' % string)

        tokens = tuple(Token(word, pos) for (word, pos) in tokens)

        type = cls._TYPES.get(''.join([t.pos for t in tokens]),
            ('EMPTY', '1-GRAM', '2-GRAM', '3-GRAM')[len(tokens)])
    except:
        logging.error('Cannot create token out of string %s', string)
        raise

    return DocumentFeature(type, tokens)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, especially for spotting the problem with counting underscores and slashes. You corrected implementation is also ~5% faster on my machine.

Regarding your first point, invalid input strings are due to data formatting. Since I'm dealing with natural language, there will inevitably be a small number of such tokens. There's nothing that can be done about that and I don't consider this to be exceptional. However, having more than 3 tokens violates a hard constraint and indicates a problem with my own code.